# How to solve Native promise missing Error in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, promise, oauth-2.0, google-api, nodemailer

I was trying to use google API to send mail through Nodemailer

Getting this error multiple times;

Code:

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    CLIENT_ID,
    CLEINT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URI
  );
  oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

  async function sendMail() {
    try {
      const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
  
      const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          type: 'OAuth2',
          user: 'email',
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: CLEINT_SECRET,
          refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
          accessToken: accessToken,
        },
      });
  
      const mailOptions = {
        from: 'SENDER NAME <email>',
        to: 'to email address here',
        subject: 'Hello from gmail using API',
        text: 'Hello from gmail email using API',
        html: '<h1>Hello from gmail email using API</h1>',
      };
  
      const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
  
  sendMail()
    .then((result) => console.log('Email sent...', result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

When I started running the code it passed through then function and showing the error in .then() only this error is not caught by .catch() but by.then() Not getting any modern javascript solution

```
Email sent... Error: native promise missing, set fetch.Promise to your favorite alternative
    at fetch (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1401:9)
    at Gaxios._defaultAdapter (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:111:28)
    at Gaxios._request (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:126:49)
    at Gaxios.request (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:107:21)
    at Object.request (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\index.js:30:29)
    at DefaultTransporter.request (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\transporters.js:74:29)
    at OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:172:44)
    at OAuth2Client.refreshToken (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:150:24)
    at OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:196:30)
    at OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (E:\WORK\D-FLOW\C-Flow\C-FLow-Back-end\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:216:34)
```

Comment: 1. In the `catch{ }` block, `return error` sends the error down the returned Promise's success path to `.then()`. By replacing `return error` with `throw error;`, the error will be caught & handled by the `.catch(error => console.log(error.message))` clause.

Comment: 2. Looks like you are trying to run the code in an antiquated environment that doesn't have native Promise. You'll need to run in a more up-to-date environment or `require()` a 3rd party Promise implementation - suggest Bluebird.